# Repeat a string with matlab

Tags: string, matlab, repeat

How can I employ repmat to produce the vector below;

```
sysHealthy={'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys'}
```

I tried:

```
A=repmat({'sys'},1,5);
unique_cell = {sprintf('%3s;',A{:})};
```

but it produces the put below:

```
{'sys;sys;sys;sys;sys;'}
```

This output has two problems: first, in doesn't have double quotation above each sys and second, it has an ; at the end of the array. I would like to get something like

```
sysHealthy={'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys'}.
```

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? What were you expecting? I mean what is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: @TusharNakini You are right. I modified the question

Comment: Doesn't `A=repmat({'sys'},1,5);` answer your question? If it's just about getting a colon vector, swap 1 and 5.

Comment: @O'Neil : No, because it creates 
    {'sys'}
    {'sys'}
    {'sys'}
    {'sys'}
    {'sys'}

Comment: @Juliette. Based on your comments to the answer, you need to specify exactly the type and shape of the output you are expecting. I'm beginning to suspect that part of the problem is a lack of understanding of the types you are working with.

Comment: @Mad the code is modifed and the problem is solved. Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following lines --

```
charLength = 3; repCount = 5;
A=repmat('sys',repCount,1);    % Creates a column vector
sysHealthy = mat2cell(A, repmat(1, [1,repCount]),charLength); % Convert them into cell.
```

Comment: Thank you, Tushar, but it doesn't produce what I meant as {'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys'}, the output of your code is very different

Comment: @Juliette, aren't you looking for a cell of strings including the double quote? When you run `sysHealthy={'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys'}`, it produces a 5x1 cell. So, I came up with the solution based on that including the double quote.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tushar, but no I am not looking for the string with double quotes, What I need is as strict as the format that I presented as {'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys'}

Comment: @Juliette, I edited the code and got rid of the double quote. This is what you want?

Comment: still not :( because the output that your code produces {'sys'}{'sys'}{'sys'}{'sys'}{'sys'} (columnwise) but what I need is {'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys';'sys'}

Comment: From your notation, it seems like a 5x1 cell of strings but I guess you need something else. So, tell us what you do with the `sysHealthy` variable?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I would use it for N-way ANOVA